# SQL subquery on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I think what I am after is fairly elementary, but I haven't been able to get the expected results through my experiments so far.

I am operating on one table, where the values from one known row determine which other rows from the same table are selected.

To illustrate what I want in two queries:

```
SELECT id, gender, sport, age
    FROM 
        person 
    WHERE 
       id = '123';

-- using id, gender, sport and age as inputs into the next query
SELECT id, age, sport, gender 
    FROM 
        person 
    WHERE 
       id != $1 AND looking_for_gender = $2 AND looking_for_sport = $3 AND min_age <= $4;
```

I've been trying different varieties of joins and subqueries in the from clause but not being able to get a satisfactory result to get the same from a single query.

Thanks in advance for any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.age, p.sport, p.gender 
FROM person p cross join
     (select * from person where id  = 123
     ) p1
WHERE p.id <> p1.id AND p.looking_for_gender = p1.looking_for_gender AND
      p.looking_for_sport = p1.looking_for_sport AND p.min_age <= p1.min_age;
```

Comment: Thanks, the subquery is what got me on the right track.